# How to load content of child page into div in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to load content of child page-1 into div of child page-2. I have tried to load the content using jquery, but it loads entire page including master page. I want to load only child page content excluding master page content. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It not clear if that previous page was loaded, or you looking to grab that whole page? You could create that first page as NOT being part of the master page, and create it as stand alone page. Then jQuery could then load/pull that page.

Comment: That's good idea. Don't we have any option to load the child page alone?

Comment: yes, see below - it seems to load the other page - even a page that supposed to be a child page - and it only loads in the page into that div - it works rather nice. As noted below - you could always use a iFrame - but that would also show the menu bar again in that iFrame - the below does not - so it does quite much want one would want.

Answer (score 0):

I am betting that you have jQuery available here.

So, to load a page - even one that was setup as a child to a master page?

this works quite well:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  OnClientClick="getpage();return false"   />

<div id="myotherpage">
</div>

<script>
    function getpage() {
        alert('hello');
        $.get("/WebForm5.aspx", function (data) {
            $("#myotherpage").html(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

So, in above, I want to get/grab/load the WebForm5.aspx page right into that div.

In this example, EVEN if WebForm5.aspx WAS attached to  master, the above seems to work rather nice.

The other way? Well of course the iFrame idea - that works.
(but a iFrame would also re-produce the menu bar - the above does not).

but, above does work quite nice - even the code behind for that page seems to run just fine.

Now, I just dropped in a button - you click on it, and it does load the other page into the div - but you can have that js code run on page load - say document ready, or even just place the above code in the script not wrapped in a function.

Comment: The code you have given didn't work as it loads the entire page with master page. As you said in comment, I have created a child page as stand alone page and it works as I expected. Thanks for your help :-)